# Passing Google Insights - Ensure text remains visible during webfont load

Tags: fonts

I purchased a web template which includes the following code to import Google fonts:

```
    @import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat:400,500,600,700,800,800i,900');
```

I'm aware this URL resolves to 35+ @font-face declarations, which seems crazy, but so be it.

I have a few questions?

1) Why do the font face declarations not include a font-display attribute if Google PageSpeed requires it?

2) Should I be using the import syntax, a link or just embed the font-face declarations from the URL? (I've seen pros and cons for both)?

3) If I stick with the import syntax or a link how can I then apply a font-display setting?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're using google fonts you should add

```
&display=swap
```

at the end so in your case it should be

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat:400,500,600,700,800,800i,900&display=swap');
```

Comment: I did not know you could add the font-display descriptor as a url param, I actually ended up declaring all the font-faces directly in the code to add the descriptor. I can now change it back, thanks so much

Answer (score 0):

I agree that you should use font-display swap value here but it would be even more efficient to just select the fonts that you actually care about (yeah, reduce the fonts to a few you use, don't overload your store with 35+ fonts you need to fetch for a single page) and store them locally. No need to jump over hoops to do this right now, Google has been more than loyal to folks who want to host fonts on their own servers ([link](https://onilab.com/blog/magento-google-pagespeed-insights-optimization-guide/)). So basically what I'm saying buying a web template was probably suboptimal since it's so unnecessarily complicated.